# If I were you I would tell my/your friends to respect my/your boundaries. How to choose the correct possessive pronouns in this structure?

Tags: possessives, conditionals

Assuming your sibling telling you that his friends do not respect his boundaries, what would be your answer using the "If I were you..." structure? I see native speakers saying something like:

- If I were you I would tell your friends to respect your boundaries.

but I think something like the following sentence would make more sense, although I couldn't find any evidence online to support it:

- If I were you I would tell my friend to respect my boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. "If I were you" is a common hypothetical situation. If you were really someone else then their friends would be your friends. But that is overthinking the expression a little. The common way to use this is to continue to refer to anyone or anything as you would if you were just giving them advice. In your example, "their friends" should remain their friends.

It would be different if you said "*if I were in your situation*". This hypothetically puts your into the same situation as the other person. Using this or similar expressions, you would speak about what you would do.

For example:

- If I were you, I'd tell your friends to respect your boundaries
- If I were in your situation, I'd tell my friends to respect my boundaries

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, although I can find it becoming offensive or awkward in some context. Can you refer me to some reference on the topic?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork if there were a guide to using the idiom I think you'd find it as easily as I could. There may be exceptions, but if you're talking about "your friends" it would just be confusing to say "my friends". What if the advice was "tell your mom"? If you said "tell **my** mom" they'd wonder why they should tell *your* mom instead of their own.

Comment: Agree with you. However, on the other hand, I find it rather uncomfortable to say "I would have sex with your wife more often" vs "I would have sex with my wife more often." I agree that your sentiment seems more natural in general though

Comment: I'd say it's usually safer to continue with the hypothetical identity rather than abandon it mid-sentence (mid-clause even): 
"If I were you, I'd watch my p's and q's," for example, sounds more logical and idiomatic than "If I were you, I'd watch your p's and q's."

Comment: An even clearer example of the problems with abandoning the hypothetical mid-sentence  would be "If I were you, I'd use your common sense" ... and another one "If I were you, I'd get out of bed and put your clothes on."

Comment: I appreciate the issue with the confusion between "your friends" and "my friends" but I think Astralbee's cure is probably worse than the disease in too many cases.  The context will almost always clarify who we're talking about, and where it doesn't perhaps we should consider abandoning the expression altogether.